# php file to array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a text document with a bunch of text and I want to grab each line in "allVersions" and store them to an array.

text document

```
bible.versions = {
// prebuild version array
versionData: null,

// versions by key
versionsByKey: {},

getVersion: function(key) {
    return this.versionsByKey[key];
},

allVersions: [
'ar_etr',
'ar_vady',
'el_tisch',
'en_kjv',
'en_wbtc',
'fr_s21',
'he_wlc'

],

loadingVersionIndex: -1,

loadingCallback: null,

loadNextVersion: function() {
```

php

```
$myarray = file_get_contents('file.js');
```

resulting array

```
$myarray = array('ar_etr', 'ar_vady', 'el_tisch', 'en_kjv', 'en_wbtc', 'fr_s21', 'he_wlc');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the File function in PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

This function reads an entire text file into an array, one line of text per array index.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myarray = explode('\n', file_get_contents("filename.txt"));
```

`file_get_contents()` returns a string containing the file, and `explode(<delimiter>, <string>)` splits the string into an array based on the delimeter.

But Matt's answer is better:

```
file("filename.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file is supposed to be [json](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) then you can use [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$myarray = json_decode(file_get_contents('file.js'), TRUE);
```

The second argument of `TRUE` makes `$myarray` an array instead of an object.